# timeline error in R: ‘min’ not meaningful for factors

Tags: r, timeline

My original dataset

`df`

```
   bugid           timestamp                    commenter     Owner.
1  18348 2011-07-10 12:26:00        nick.sho...@gmail.com     No
2  18348 2011-07-11 10:47:16 ralf%and...@gtempaccount.com     No
3  18348 2011-07-11 17:44:50           tnor...@google.com    Yes
4  18348 2011-07-11 18:13:17             nic...@gmail.com     No
5  18348 2011-07-11 18:14:39        nick.sho...@gmail.com     No
6  18348 2011-07-11 18:23:54        nick.sho...@gmail.com     No
7  18348 2011-07-13 14:36:31           vt903...@gmail.com     No
8  18348 2011-07-15 18:16:12           tnor...@google.com    Yes
9  18348 2011-07-15 18:17:54           tnor...@google.com    Yes
10 18348 2011-07-26 06:35:04           hustd...@gmail.com     No
11 18348 2011-09-04 21:34:03        baykalca...@gmail.com     No
12 18348 2011-09-13 23:14:20           tnor...@google.com    Yes
13 18348 2011-10-19 18:49:22             x...@android.com     No
```

> dput(df)

```
structure(list(bugid = c(18348L, 18348L, 18348L, 18348L, 18348L, 
18348L, 18348L, 18348L, 18348L, 18348L, 18348L, 18348L, 18348L
), timestamp = structure(1:13, .Label = c("2011-07-10 12:26:00", 
"2011-07-11 10:47:16", "2011-07-11 17:44:50", "2011-07-11 18:13:17", 
"2011-07-11 18:14:39", "2011-07-11 18:23:54", "2011-07-13 14:36:31", 
"2011-07-15 18:16:12", "2011-07-15 18:17:54", "2011-07-26 06:35:04", 
"2011-09-04 21:34:03", "2011-09-13 23:14:20", "2011-10-19 18:49:22"
), class = "factor"), commenter = structure(c(4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 8L), .Label = c("baykalca...@gmail.com", 
"hustd...@gmail.com", "nic...@gmail.com", "nick.sho...@gmail.com", 
"ralf%and...@gtempaccount.com", "tnor...@google.com", "vt903...@gmail.com", 
"x...@android.com"), class = "factor"), Owner. = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
"Yes"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

I then do the following:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$timestamp)
```

The dataset thus becomes:

```
df
```

```
   bugid           timestamp                    commenter Owner.       date
1  18348 2011-07-10 12:26:00        nick.sho...@gmail.com     No 2011-07-10
2  18348 2011-07-11 10:47:16 ralf%and...@gtempaccount.com     No 2011-07-11
3  18348 2011-07-11 17:44:50           tnor...@google.com    Yes 2011-07-11
4  18348 2011-07-11 18:13:17             nic...@gmail.com     No 2011-07-11
5  18348 2011-07-11 18:14:39        nick.sho...@gmail.com     No 2011-07-11
6  18348 2011-07-11 18:23:54        nick.sho...@gmail.com     No 2011-07-11
7  18348 2011-07-13 14:36:31           vt903...@gmail.com     No 2011-07-13
8  18348 2011-07-15 18:16:12           tnor...@google.com    Yes 2011-07-15
9  18348 2011-07-15 18:17:54           tnor...@google.com    Yes 2011-07-15
10 18348 2011-07-26 06:35:04           hustd...@gmail.com     No 2011-07-26
11 18348 2011-09-04 21:34:03        baykalca...@gmail.com     No 2011-09-04
12 18348 2011-09-13 23:14:20           tnor...@google.com    Yes 2011-09-13
13 18348 2011-10-19 18:49:22             x...@android.com     No 2011-10-19
```

I removed the timestamp column thinking that the column must be causing problem:

```
remove.cols = names(df) %in% c("timestamp")
df.pruned <- df[!remove.cols]
```

However, when I try to generate the timeline using the following:

```
timelineS(df.pruned)
```

I get the error:

> Error in Summary.factor(c(4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 
>   :    ‘min’ not meaningful for factors

Tried converting date field to numeric after reading a thread on a similar issue. But nothing seems to solve the problem.
Please help.

Comment: You should try `dput` with your `df` rather than an image - makes it easier to help and clean up the question.

Comment: From the help: `df Data frame for events and dates. First column for event names and second column for dates in Date class.`

Comment: Where does `timelineS` come from? We can't run this code—can't call a function on a picture of a dataset—but the error message says you've got something encoded as a factor that likely shouldn't be

Comment: I have removed the image of the dataset and included text so that it can be copied. This is my first question with a table and hence still figuring how to include one properly. df is the name of my dataset in R.

Comment: @ReshmaR Run `dput(df)` and copy that output into your question.

Comment: @Hatt Have updated with the output of dput(df)

Comment: @camille Have removed the images

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the timelineS package states that the data frame you feed the timelineS function can only consist of two columns - one for events and one for dates:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/timelineS/versions/0.1.1/topics/timelineS

Is your objective to make a timeline showing the dates when various commenters made comments?

If so, just strip your dataframe down to the commenter field and the date field.

```
 library(dplyr)
 df_pruned <- df %>%
 select(c("commenter", "date"))

 library(timelineS)
 timelineS(df_pruned)
```

Should get you started... you may want to explore some of the formatting options to make the timeline more visually appealing.